# Azure AD Single Sign On - Can't Connect to the Service Issue

Tags: azure-active-directory

We developed a Windows Store 8.1 enterprise app in that we implemented azure single sign on. At the time of development and testing it was worked fine, then we deployed the app into client organization where we have a domain joined pc's that time the AAD Sign On returning an error like below
[image]

The PC has internet but still I am getting this error. If I open the app without connecting PC to my organization network ( means in home network or outside of organization) it's working. I am able to sign in successfully. But only when I open the app with in the organization not able to do.

Client have Office365 AD managing using a third party  AD tool and Azure AD. In app we are using Azure ad.

Anybody please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by something that prevents your app from getting the rights to use your intranet. There are various moving parts that must be in the right place for this to work: the app must request the right capabilities, you must use the app SID as redirect URI, and you need to flip the UseCorporateNetwork bit of AUthenticationContext to true. Those are all documented in the readme of the windows store sample, available at https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-WindowsStore. Please take a look at the readme and ensure that you are doing all those things. If it still doesn't work we can move to deeper troubleshooting.